# Запуск скрипта через тег <a>

Tags: javascript, html

Есть скрипт

```
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.innerHTML = ":root { background-color: #fefefe; filter: invert(100%); } * { background-color: inherit; } img:not([src*=\'.svg\']), video { filter: invert(100%); }";
document.body.appendChild(css);
```

Есть его минифицированая версия встроенная в тег `<a>`.

```
<a href="javascript:var css=document.createElement('style');css.type='text/css',css.innerHTML=':root { background-color: #fefefe; filter: invert(100%); } * { background-color: inherit; } img:not([src*='.svg']), video { filter: invert(100%); }',document.body.appendChild(css);">
```

По нажатии на ссылку выдает ошибку

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal ']), video { filter: invert(100%); }'
```

Что не так, не могу понять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
<a href="javascript:var css=document.createElement('style');css.type='text/css',css.innerHTML=':root { background-color: #fefefe; filter: invert(100%); } * { background-color: inherit; } img:not([src*=\'.svg\']), video { filter: invert(100%); }',document.body.appendChild(css);">
```

Собственно весь ответ из Вашего же вопроса.

Comment: Вы экранировали символы? Или что вы сделали?

Comment: Да, просто экранировал.

Comment: @brachkoff, кстати посмотрите в сторону webpack. Он нормально там всё минифицирует из коробки. Потому что судя по ошибке webpack Вы не используете.